# Convert a bluetooth 16-bit service uuid into a CBUUID

Tags: ios, bluetooth, xamarin.ios

In my `iOS` application, I need have a `CBUUID` variable as a GATT characteristic such as the Device Name (0x2A00). How can I convert the 16-bit format (0x2A00) into a `CBUUID`?

I am writing this app in `Xamarin.iOS`, but an answer in native iOS would work for me as well.

Comment: Do you have it as a string?  If so `CBUUID(string:"2A00")`

Comment: No I have it as `int32`

Comment: You can use `String(format:”%04x”,is)` to convert it to a hex string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CBUUID(string:)` initialiser.  If you don't already have the ID as a string, you can convert it using `String(format:)` or similar.

e.g.

```
let identifier:UInt16 = 0x2a00
let idString = String(format:"%04x",identifier)
let cbuudid = CBUUID(string: idString)
```